# Memory leak during parallel computing

Tags: parallelization, memory

I have a memory leak during parallel computing. The problem seems to be in how a large variable is passed to kernels but I can't think of anything to fix that.

Consider this simplified example:

```
data = Association[Map[Rule[#, RandomReal[{0, 100}, 1000]] &, Range[1, 10000]]];
Clear[f];
ParallelMap[f[data, #] &, Range[1, 10000]];
```

In this, f[] can be any function and I have left it undefined on purpose. In real program f[] is a complex lookup function that takes data snippets from variable *data* according to the second argument. The function runs with no problems on one kernel. But when I run this code at 4 CPUs, the 16 GB of RAM that I have are quickly extinguished and the program crashes. Variable *data* does not even have to be the association as in the example - it could just be a square matrix of random reals to the same effect.

Any thoughts of how should I distribute *data* variable between kernels so not to cause a memory leak?

Comment: Are you sure that distributing `data` is the problem? If `f` is undefined, what can happen in the worst case is that `data` is copied 10000 times and stored in the resulting expressions. If I am not mistaken, then that would be about 880 GB...

Comment: By the way, one typically means something different from what you describe when one refers to "memory leak".